# how to get ip address of centos 7 vm?

Tags: networking, ip, virtualbox

I have a centos 7 virtual machine on my mac.
I'm trying to get its ip but can't find it.

[image: ifconfig result]

and

[image: ip addr result]

and
[image: etc/sysconfig/network and /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcg-enp0s3]

Comment: I can see you have set ONBOOT='Yes' but have you tried running `nmtui` and see what it shows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only worked when I assigned it to a static ip address.
added this to  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcg-enp0s3

```
IPADDR = <add-ip-addr>
PREFIX = <add-prefix>
GATEWAY = <add-gateway>
DNS1 = 8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are not getting any IP to your interface `enp0s3`. It might be a missconfiguration on the DHCP server, your network settings for that vm or on the vm network configuration.

Make sure that:

- your vm is on `bridge` or `NAT` mode, with the adapter connected.
- `/etc/sysconfig/network` and `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcg-enp0s3` have the right settings.

*After OP being updated:*

Remove `UUID=...`

Comment: my vm on a bridge mode.
and I added the settings to the question, do you thinks there's anything missing?

Comment: remove `UUID=...`

Comment: Alex already provided the answer to why you're not getting a valid eth connection. Just like to mention that after you reboot your machine you can check the IP adress with either ip addr or hostname -i.